# Is it possible to move everything on a slide a set distance (inches) in one direction in PowerPoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to move everything on a slide a set distance (inches) in one direction. For example, everything on slide 1 (odd) slides I want to move 1 inch to the right and slide 2 (even) slides 1 inch to the left. With this repeated throughout the presentation. Is this possible? I've sort of worked this out so far but it doesn't work... Thanks, Jay

```
    Sub Button10()
Dim i As Long

With ActivePresentation.Slides

For i = 1 To .count
      If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
        MoveRight
      End If
      If i Mod 2 = 2 Then
        MoveLeft
      End If
    Next i

End With

MsgBox "Completed!", vbExclamation

End Sub

Sub MoveRight()

Dim i As Long

With ActivePresentation
        For Each Slide In .Slides
        For Each Shape In Slide.Shapes
                With Shape
            Shape.Left = Shape.Left + (1.5 * 72)
            End With
        Next
        Next
        End With

End Sub

Sub MoveLeft()

With ActivePresentation
        For Each Slide In .Slides
        For Each Shape In Slide.Shapes
                With Shape
            Shape.Left = Shape.Left - (1.5 * 72)
            End With
        Next
        Next
        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do that. The Mod operator divides the slide index number by 2 and returns the remainder. When the remainder is 1, it's an odd numbered slide, when the remainder is 0 it's even:

```
Sub MoveShapes()
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShape As Shape

    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If oSlide.SlideIndex Mod 2 = 1 Then 'Odd numbered slide
            For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
                oShape.Left = oShape.Left + 72
            Next oShape
        Else
            For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
                oShape.Left = oShape.Left - 72
            Next oShape
        End If
    Next oSlide
End Sub
```